# C# 7 Tuples and names in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, c#-7.0

With C# 7 new Tuple feature we should be able to access fields by it's names derived from the type.

```
public (double lat, double lng) GetLatLng(string address) { ... }

var ll = GetLatLng("some address"); 
Console.WriteLine($"Lat: {ll.lat}, Long: {ll.lng}");
```

This is not possible in .NET Core. Why? -> **Works only with Item1; Item2. Not with .lat .lng.**

Thanks

Comment: Could it be you need to add the nuget package for it? https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/

Comment: It most certainly is possible to do this with .NET Core. Does your code compile with `$"Lat: {ll.Item1}, Long: {ll.Item2}"` but not when using the tuple's names? This seems unlikely, but is what you imply with your question. A bit more info is needed, please.

Comment: I wrote that Item1 and Item2 names are working for tuple, named fields like .lat and .lng not.

Comment: @OndrejTomcik post the *exact* error message. I can't reproduce any problem once I add the package. The named fields *do* work

Comment: @OndrejTomcik did you target an earlier C# language version perhaps? Are you using a pre-release version of VS 2017? If you create a new, clean .NET Core project with just the snippet you provided you'll see that there is no problem with the compiler. Intellisense may be slow to update itself after adding the package. Once you are satisfied that named tuples do work, you'll have to find what's different with your project

Comment: Voting to close this as "*Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself*". "It doesn't work" doesn't fit that bill. Lots more info is required in the question to make this a useful question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Visual Studio 2017 Intellisense may be slow to update itself after adding the `System.ValueTuple` package and keep displaying error squigglies even when there is no compilation error. Compiling the project though shows that named tuples *are* working. A quick fix is to re-open the source file or solution.

**ORIGINAL**

The error message explains that 'Predefined type `System.ValueTuple'2 is not defined or imported`. You need to add the [System.ValueTuple](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/) package from NuGet in order to use named tuples.

Once you add the package, the code compiles:

```
class Program
{
    static (double lat, double lng) GetLatLng(string address)
    {
        return (1, 1);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        var ll = GetLatLng("some address");
        Console.WriteLine($"Lat: {ll.lat}, Long: {ll.lng}");
    }
}
```

[Scott Hanselman shows](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudio2017CanAutomaticallyRecommendNuGetPackagesForUnknownTypes.aspx) how to configure Visual Studio 2017 to automatically suggest NuGet packages for missing types by enabling the settings in `Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Using Directives`.

After you enable the `Suggest usings for types in NuGet packages` setting, the Quick Fix menu for the missing tuples shows `Install package 'System.ValueTuple'` :

[image: Install missing package]

The `Find this type on nuget.org` menu is a similar ReSharper feature

Comment: I don't have problem with error message, I have System.ValueTuple package installed and tuples are working properly. Problem is with names, which are not proposed by the compiler itself. Still proposing only Item1 ...

Comment: First, the snippet works as long as you add the package. So the compiler *does* recognize the names. Second, what does "not proposed by the compiler"? The compiler doesn't propose anything. Do you mean that intellisense doesn't display the names?

Comment: I had to restart VS... No comment :)

Comment: @OndrejTomcik I didn't. Besides, the code did compile without issue. Intellisense was updated a bit later, but I didn't even have to reload the solution. OTOH I also have Resharper and sometimes it doesn't work that well with VS, sometimes it does